# Express $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-N)^k}{k!(x+k)}$ using $e^{-x}$

Tags: summation, taylor-expansion

You can see that this sum

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-N)^k}{k!(x+k)}$$

looks shockingly like the Taylor expansion of $e^{-x}$ except for that $x+k$ term in the denominator. So, can anyone express this sum somehow using $e^{-x}$?

Comment: Please use LaTeX to properly format the mathematics (so it is easier to read). See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: I assume $N \in \mathbb{N}, x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I assume you mean it looks like the expansion for $e^{-N}$, not $e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 1):

The series is equal to $N^{-x}\gamma(x,N)$, where
$$
\gamma(x,N):=\int_0^Nt^{x-1}e^{-t}\,dt \tag{1}
$$
is the lower [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

Proof:
\begin{align}
N^{-x}\int_0^Nt^{x-1}e^{-t}\,dt
&=N^{-x}\int_0^N\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^kt^{x-1+k}}{k!}dt \\
&=N^{-x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^kN^{x+k}}{k!(x+k)} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-N)^{k}}{k!(x+k)}. \tag{2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Another form for it is:$$\begin{split}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-N)^k}{k!(x+k)} &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-N)^k}{k!}\int_0^1 u^{x+k-1}du\\
&= \int_0^1u^{x-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-Nu)^k}{k!}du\\
&=\int_0^1u^{x-1}e^{-Nu}du
\end{split}
$$

Comment: +1. To rephrase OP: "shockingly like" the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) but not quite.